# \cellcolor overrides borders even with \hhline, how do I fix?

Tags: tables, colortbl, cell

[Here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/pfqwfcmfqfpy) is a minimal working example of my code. When I compile it using overleaf online TeX editor I get the expected result and everything works fine, while when I compile it using texstudio here is what I get

[image]

No matter which PDF viewer I use, I always keep getting this problem where borders are overlapped by the color. If I zoom all the way to 300%+ I can see something that might resemble a border. I tried everything I found here on tex.stackexchange but I didn't manage to get it to look like I want it to. Knowing that it might be the viewer's fault doesn't help, I need a way to workaround it, like getting thicker borders (I tried but didn't manage to) or to use a solid color image scaled to match the inner cell size (i.e. without the border). Any suggestion is greatly appreciated, this is driving me nuts.

I'm willing to consider any other way to represent the fact that I want to consider just the cells filled in blue and the one filled in yellow (always to be picked, while the blue ones can be any random subset of the remaining cells. TIA

**EDIT**: I'm gonna copy the MWE code from the link in case it dies, for the future visitors:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{colortbl} % \cellcolor
\usepackage{hhline} % trying to keep borders visible using \cellcolor
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pifont}% "don't care"
\newcommand*{\eleminvalid}{\ensuremath{\text{\scriptsize{\ding{54}}}}} % "don't care"

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty} %Caption table without Table text and number 

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}\noindent
        \begin{center}
            \captionof{table}{Stato obiettivo}\noindent
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
                \cellcolor{yellow!25}          &  1 & 2  & 3 \\  \hhline{|-|-|-|-|}
                                        4  &  5 & 6  & 7 \\ \hhline{|-|-|-|-|}
                                        8  &  9 & 10 & 11 \\ \hhline{|-|-|-|-|}
                                        12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\ \hhline{|-|-|-|-|}
                \end{tabular}
        \end{center}\columnbreak\noindent
        \begin{center}
            \captionof{table}{Generico sottoproblema}\noindent
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
                    \cellcolor{yellow!25}  &  $\eleminvalid$ & $\eleminvalid$  & \cellcolor{blue!25}\textcolor{blue!25}{3}\\ \hhline{|-|-|-|-|}
                    $\eleminvalid$  &  $\eleminvalid$ & $\eleminvalid$  & \cellcolor{blue!25}\textcolor{blue!25}{7} \\ \hhline{|-|-|-|-|}
                    $\eleminvalid$  &  $\eleminvalid$ & $\eleminvalid$ & \cellcolor{blue!25}\textcolor{blue!25}{11} \\ \hhline{|-|-|-|-|}
                    \cellcolor{blue!25}\textcolor{blue!25}{12} & \cellcolor{blue!25}\textcolor{blue!25}{13} & \cellcolor{blue!25}\textcolor{blue!25}{14} & \cellcolor{blue!25}\textcolor{blue!25}{15} \\ \hhline{|-|-|-|-|}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}\noindent
    \end{multicols}\noindent
\end{document}
```

Comment: you've shown no code so it is hard to help but try using a package such as nicematrix that draws the lines after the colours (not really possible in the colortbl approach)

Comment: @DavidCarlise I attached a link with the code, it's the first word in the post

Comment: so you did, sorry I missed that, but please add it inline as a code block, your question is archived here for ever and will be meaningless if you fix that project so the issue goes.

Comment: and now I tried the link it just says: Restricted, sorry you don't have permission to load this page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ouch, fixed, thanks for telling me.

Comment: Take a look at the `nicematrix` package. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines]{cccc}
\CodeBefore
\cellcolor{yellow}{1-1}
\rectanglecolor{blue}{1-4}{3-4}
\Body
& 1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}` should get you started.

Comment: @Bafforasta you may have fixed the permission sbut you have not fixed it to show the code here.

Comment: @leandriis this is general good advice "avoid David's packages"

Comment: incidentally if I look at your [overleaf project it looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FENFo.png)

Comment: Please, copy code from link in the question. After while your link can become death and site members will not know, what is your problem. BTW, in my test all lines are visible (in Sumatra).

Comment: @Zarko: I'm not home right now, I will update as soon as I get back.

Comment: @Leandriis I tried running your code and I get "NiceTabular environment undefined" error... is there any extra step to do that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tabularray` package, which doesn't have these issues. It also offers a keyval syntax, which simplifies the creation of your tables.

[image: table output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{colortbl} % \cellcolor
\usepackage{hhline} % trying to keep borders visible using \cellcolor
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pifont}% "don't care"
\newcommand*{\eleminvalid}{\ensuremath{\text{\scriptsize{\ding{54}}}}} % "don't care"

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty} %Caption table without Table text and number 

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}\noindent
        \begin{center}
            \captionof{table}{Stato obiettivo}\noindent
            \begin{tblr}{
                    colspec=cccc,
                    hlines, vlines, rowsep=0pt,
                }
                \SetCell{yellow!25} &  1 & 2  & 3 \\  
                4  &  5 & 6  & 7 \\ 
                8  &  9 & 10 & 11 \\ 
                12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\ 
            \end{tblr}
        \end{center}\columnbreak\noindent
        \begin{center}
            \captionof{table}{Generico sottoproblema}\noindent
            \begin{tblr}{
                    colspec=cccc,
                    hlines, vlines, rowsep=0pt,
                    column{4}={blue!25}, row{4}={blue!25},
                }
                \SetCell{yellow!25}  &  $\eleminvalid$ & $\eleminvalid$  & 3 \\
                $\eleminvalid$  &  $\eleminvalid$ & $\eleminvalid$  & 7 \\
                $\eleminvalid$  &  $\eleminvalid$ & $\eleminvalid$ & 11 \\
                12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
            \end{tblr}
        \end{center}\noindent
    \end{multicols}\noindent
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, the output will be perfect in all PDF viewers (because the rules are drawn with Tikz after the colored panels).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand*{\eleminvalid}{\ensuremath{\text{\scriptsize{\ding{54}}}}}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty} %Caption table without Table text and number 

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}\noindent
\begin{center}
    \captionof{table}{Stato obiettivo}\noindent
    \begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[colortbl-like,hvlines]
    \cellcolor{yellow!25} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\  
    4  &  5 & 6  & 7 \\ 
    8  &  9 & 10 & 11 \\ 
    12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\ 
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}\columnbreak\noindent
\begin{center}
    \captionof{table}{Generico sottoproblema}\noindent
    \begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[colortbl-like,hvlines]
    \cellcolor{yellow!25}  &  $\eleminvalid$ & $\eleminvalid$  & \cellcolor{blue!25}\textcolor{blue!25}{3}\\ 
    $\eleminvalid$  &  $\eleminvalid$ & $\eleminvalid$  & \cellcolor{blue!25}\textcolor{blue!25}{7} \\ 
    $\eleminvalid$  &  $\eleminvalid$ & $\eleminvalid$ & \cellcolor{blue!25}\textcolor{blue!25}{11} \\ 
    \cellcolor{blue!25}\textcolor{blue!25}{12} & \cellcolor{blue!25}\textcolor{blue!25}{13} & \cellcolor{blue!25}\textcolor{blue!25}{14} & \cellcolor{blue!25}\textcolor{blue!25}{15} \\ 
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}\noindent
\end{multicols}\noindent
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

As suplement to @marv answer. A bit more concise code ...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pifont}% "don't care"
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}\centering
    \caption*{Stato obiettivo}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {*{4}{Q[c,2ex]}},
                 abovesep= 4pt
                }
\SetCell{yellow!25}
    &  1 &  2  &  3 \\
 4  &  5 &  6  &  7 \\
 8  &  9 & 10  & 11 \\
12  & 13 & 14  & 15 \\
    \end{tblr}%
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}\centering
    \caption*{Generico sottoproblema}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                   colspec = {*{4}{Q[c,2ex]}},
                 column{4} = {blue!25},
                    row{4} = {blue!25},
                  abovesep = 4pt
                }
\SetCell{yellow!25}
            & \ding{54} & \ding{54} &   \\
\ding{54}   & \ding{54} & \ding{54} &   \\
\ding{54}   & \ding{54} & \ding{54} &   \\
            &           &           &   \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{minipage}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]